# Syntax highlighter for Android application

Tags: android, syntax-highlighting

I want to write an android native app where i need to have a syntax highlighting. So does any one know if there is any syntax highlighting library available in java/android, also if it supports some level of customization, like custom color coding.

Comment: see this one maybe helpful http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter-for-android/downloads/list

Comment: If your objective is simply to display syntax-highlighted content, use any Java-based highlighter that generates HTML, then use `Html.fromHtml()` to create a `Spanned` object you can put in a `TextView` that will show the highlighting. You may need to tweak the Java-based highlighter some, if the generated HTML includes stuff that `fromHtml()` does not support and is important.

Comment: @CommonsWare Basically only syntax highlighting is not the objectiv.. rather the app i am developing should support major language like php, ROR, C# etc. So in this case does android have have any opensource/paid library like [this](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) which is used byt phpbb (basically built for php).

Comment: Android does not have a syntax highlighter. However, you write applications in Android using a programming language known as "Java", and Java has syntax highlighters that generate HTML. Android can display HTML in a `TextView` (via `Html.fromHtml()`) or a `WebView`. And, push come to shove, you could try integrating a C/C++ syntax highlighter library via the NDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare integrating c/C++ might do a job... or by displaying it as HTML. Will try both if you know c/c++ libraries please let me know . Thanks for the suggestion..  :)